# What is the best way to call a Win32 api requiring a hWnd when not on the main window thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, winapi, dispatcher

I try to call 2 Win32 API functions from a worker thread:

- SetForegroundWindow
- FlashWindowEx

Both Win32 functions require a hWnd as parameter. I try 2 different ways to get a valid hWnd:

- HwndSource source = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(window);
  IntPtr hWnd = source.Handle;
- WindowInteropHelper windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
  IntPtr hwnd = windowInteropHelper.Handle;

When calling from a working thread, I receive:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'
```

In .net Core, WPF, a Window as a "Dispatcher" property but the dispatcher has no CheckAccess or VerifyAccess.

So I have few questions:

- The 2 Win32 Api that I want to use does not require to be called from main window thread. Is there a way get a hWnd to call them directly without having any thread check?
- Why there is no CheckAccess or VerifyAccess on the Dispatcher and what does replace them both in .net Core WPF (differences from .net framework WPF)?
- What's the difference in the 2 ways I use to get the hWnd and what's the best one?
- What's the best way to do what I want to acheive?

Just as reference, this is my code. A comment show a place where exception occurs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace UnmanagedCore.WindowEx
{
    public static class WindowExtension
    {
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public static bool SetForegroundWindow(this Window window)
        {
            // WindowInteropHelper windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
            // IntPtr hwnd = windowInteropHelper.Handle;

            HwndSource source = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(window);    // System.InvalidOperationException
            IntPtr hWnd = source.Handle;
            return SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        }

        public static T RunSafeWindowAction<T>(this Window window, Func<T> func)
        {
            // Missing code here ... waiting answer from StackOverflow to write proper code
            return func();
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct FLASHWINFO
        {
            public UInt32 cbSize;
            public IntPtr hwnd;
            public UInt32 dwFlags;
            public UInt32 uCount;
            public UInt32 dwTimeout;
        }

        public enum FlashWindow : uint
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Stop flashing. The system restores the window to its original state.
            /// </summary>    
            FLASHW_STOP = 0,

            /// <summary>
            /// Flash the window caption
            /// </summary>
            FLASHW_CAPTION = 1,

            /// <summary>
            /// Flash the taskbar button.
            /// </summary>
            FLASHW_TRAY = 2,

            /// <summary>
            /// Flash both the window caption and taskbar button.
            /// This is equivalent to setting the FLASHW_CAPTION | FLASHW_TRAY flags.
            /// </summary>
            FLASHW_ALL = 3,

            /// <summary>
            /// Flash continuously, until the FLASHW_STOP flag is set.
            /// </summary>
            FLASHW_TIMER = 4,

            /// <summary>
            /// Flash continuously until the window comes to the foreground.
            /// </summary>
            FLASHW_TIMERNOFG = 12
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool FlashWindowEx(ref FLASHWINFO pwfi);

        /// <summary>
        /// Flashes a window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle to the window to flash</param>
        /// <returns>whether or not the window needed flashing</returns>
        public static bool FlashWindowEx(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            FLASHWINFO fInfo = new FLASHWINFO();

            fInfo.cbSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(fInfo));
            fInfo.hwnd = hWnd;
            fInfo.dwFlags = (int)FlashWindow.FLASHW_ALL;
            fInfo.uCount = UInt32.MaxValue;
            fInfo.dwTimeout = 0;

            return FlashWindowEx(ref fInfo);
        }

        /// Minor adjust to the code above
        /// <summary>
        /// Flashes a window until the window comes to the foreground
        /// Receives the form that will flash
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle to the window to flash</param>
        /// <returns>whether or not the window needed flashing</returns>
        public static bool FlashWindowEx(this Window window)
        {
            HwndSource source = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(window);
            IntPtr hWnd = source.Handle;
            FLASHWINFO fInfo = new FLASHWINFO();

            fInfo.cbSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(fInfo));
            fInfo.hwnd = hWnd;
            fInfo.dwFlags = (int)(FlashWindow.FLASHW_ALL | FlashWindow.FLASHW_TIMERNOFG);
            fInfo.uCount = UInt32.MaxValue;
            fInfo.dwTimeout = 0;

            return FlashWindowEx(ref fInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest use **dispatcher.invoke** in where you got exception

Comment: Thanks Akbar! Dispatcher.Invoke will surely do the CheckAccess itself but how can I do it myself? Even better, the 2 win32 api function does not require a hWnd that is thread safe, so how can I retreive a the hWnd without having this check at all?

Comment: can you check Thread.IsActive ?

Comment: [Dispatcher.CheckAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess?view=netcore-3.1#moniker-applies-to) should be available in .NET Core

Comment: @dewaffled, my project setting is     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF> and CheckAccess does not show up into intellisense???

Comment: @Akbar, IsActive is not appropriate. It is to know if the thread is running or not (started and not terminated).